# Autowired mongo repository object is null outside Application class

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, autowired, mongorepository

Many similar questions like this, but none of the solution has worked for me yet. I have a Repository interface that extends MondoRepository.

```
public interface Repository extends MongoRepository<Subject, String> {
    Subject findByName(String name);
}
```

And this is the subject class

```
public class Subject {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

The upper two files are in `/db` package

If I autowire Repository in my Application class, I'm able to use it properly.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses=Repository.class )
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

@Bean
public Service service() {
    return new Service();
}

@Autowired
private Repository repository;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    repository.save(new Subject());

    Subject subject = repository.findByName("hello");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

My `Application` class is in the root folder `/` .

Basically, this gives me no error. But if I autowire this in a Service class like this

```
public class Service {

@Autowired
private Repository repository;

public String get() {
    repository.findByName("hello");

    return "";
}
}
```

This gives me a null pointer exception in the line `repository.findByName()` . 
My `Service` class is in `/service` package .

Why does it not behave same like in the application class?
What should I do differently to be able to use repository in the service class?

What I have tried -
I tried annotating my `Service` class with `@Service, @Repository, @Component`, none of them worked.

I tried adding annonation `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Service.name)` for `Application` class, it didn't work .

Any workaround is also fine -

Comment: How is your package  set up ? Is your `Service` class located in a different packing structure from your `Application` and `Repository` class ?

Comment: Yes, `Service` class is localted in a different package. `Repository` and `Subject` classes are in `db` package, `Service` is in `service` package and `Application` class is outside.

Comment: You can annotate your `Service` with `@Service` annotation and if the `Application` class is at the root level package then your annotation should be picked up.

Comment: I tried with `@Service` annonation, it did not work. Still the same NullPointerException

Comment: Add `@ComponentScan(service package)`  annotation to the  `Application` class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because the Repository or Service hasn't been scanned by spring? have you annotated as @service, @repository or @component?

these works for me:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private Service service;


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        String subject = service.get();
        System.out.println("Hola" + subject);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    private Repository repository;

    public String get() {
        repository.findByName("hello");

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried all the three annotations individually, none of them worked. Added all the annotations that I have for `Application` class, even this did not work.